# Replacing 'NULL' with empty space

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this select

```
SELECT 
    [DtData] AS Data, [CdTelefono] AS Telefono,  
    [DsServizio] AS Servizio, [TotAvgDurata] AS DurataMedia, 
    [TotAvgAttesa] AS MediaTempoAttesa, [TotNumTime] AS NumVolte, 
    [CdQuartoDiAnno] AS Trimestre, 
    [CallbackDateTimeZone1] AS DataSchedulazione,
    CASE
       WHEN CallStatusZone1 = 'C' THEN 'Contattato' 
       WHEN CallStatusZone1 = 'M' THEN 'Max Tentativi' 
       WHEN CallStatusZone1 = 'R' THEN 'Rischedulato' 
       ELSE CallStatusZone1 
    END AS Stato,
    Cd_Risposta1_DTMF AS Risp1, Cd_Risposta2_DTMF AS Risp2, 
    Cd_Risposta3_DTMF AS Risp3, Cd_Risposta4_DTMF AS Risp4, 
    Fg_Partecipazione AS Stato
FROM
    ([CallCenter].[dbo].[TLC_ANAGRAFE_QUESTIONARIO] AG 
INNER JOIN
    ICM10IPCC10.prod_baA.dbo.DL_5040_5041 DL ON AG.CdTelefono = DL.Phone01)    
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ICM10IPCC10.Campagne.dbo.TLC_QUESTIONARIO_CUSTOMER_IVR IVR ON AG.CdTelefono = IVR.Cd_Phone01
```

and I would like to know how can I replace 'NULL' with an empty space where there's no data for the selection,

Thank you.

Comment: When asking a question, please format your code so its easy to read. This wall of code is not very easy to read at all. With respect to your actual question, look at `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`.

Comment: Do you mean `'NULL'` or `NULL`?  These are quite different.

Comment: NULL, but I've already solved, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `coalesce` function it will return 1st non null value so if your column value is null in that case it will return blank string

```
select coalesce(col1,' ') from table
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 2:**

T-SQL:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Column_to_check,'') FROM SomeTable
```

PL/SQL:

```
SELECT NVL(Column_to_check,'') FROM SomeTable
```

Also use NVL2 as below if you want to return other value from the Column_to_check:

```
NVL2(Column_to_check, value_if_NOT_null, value_if_null )
```

Comment: I've done like this



ISNULL(Cd_Risposta1_DTMF,'') as Risp1,ISNULL(Cd_Risposta2_DTMF,'') as Risp2, ISNULL(Cd_Risposta3_DTMF,'') as Risp3, ISNULL(Cd_Risposta4_DTMF,'') as Risp4